# Impala FDW for Postgres 9.5

Tags: postgresql, impala, postgres-fdw

I am looking for Impala Foreign Data Wrapper for Postgres 9.5. I have tried to figure out from the internet and can only have one reference to https://github.com/lapug/impala_fdw
But it seems the fdw is yet to be completed as per the readme file.

Can someone guide me to any other Impala FDW available which I can use to connect Postgres to Impala?

Answer (score 0):

Since Impala supports JDBC and ODBC, you've got some options.

- My [jdbc2_fdw fork with 9.5 patches](https://github.com/dbh/jdbc2_fdw/tree/update/pg95) - compiles and able to retrieve results. Not fully tested yet. Incorporates mc-soi's [jdbc2_fdw patch for PostgreSQL 9.5](https://gist.github.com/mc-soi/cce26e0e6186d416a9cc) and includes additional changes.
- [jdbc2_fdw](https://github.com/heimir-sverrisson/jdbc2_fdw) - only works with PostgreSQL 9.4 and earlier
- [odbc_fdw](https://github.com/ZhengYang/odbc_fdw)

I'm using odbc_fdw and heimir-sverrisson's jdbc2_fdw  successfully with PostgreSQL 9.4.

PostgreSQL 9.5 changed the API. I just got the jdbc2_fdw working to some degree, but had to do additional patches on the path I mentioned. It allows retrieving results from a foreign table and creating a materialized view on it. More testing is needed. Link shared above.